# SVG content is cut off when scrolling in Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I have a set of simple SVG files in a scrollable DIV. You may see a demo here: http://www.ron2.byethost16.com/docviewertest.html This SVG list can be scrolled without problems in all major desktop browsers including Chrome and in some mobile browsers (Edge Mobile, Firefox Mobile and Android browser). However, in Chrome Mobile there is a problem: when scrolling it fast, some content on some SVG images is cut off and is not displayed, after a bit scrolling it may reappear but other content may disappear and so on (see these screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbIuj.jpg).
My HTML page code follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    iframe {
        width: 935px;
        height: 1210px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<iframe src="page1.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page2.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page3.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page4.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page5.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page6.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page7.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page8.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page9.svg"></iframe>
<iframe src="page10.svg"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect it is a bug in Chromium because I experience it not only in Chrome Mobile but in applications built with Crosswalk. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem or is it indeed a browser bug?